# What is the best practise for AWS EC2-Instance backup/termination/start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want my existing EC2-Instances, to automatically get backupped, terminated and later on get started with the backupped status again. The backup and termination should get done in the evening and get started again in the morning.

I already figured out that the EBS should get a backup on a S3 and for the Instance itself i could use an AMI (And maybe the EC2-Image-Builder?). It all should get triggered by Cloudwatch Events in combination with AWS Lambda.

Do you know if this idea is possible to perform, or if there is a better one?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: What are you _actual_ goals? That is, _why_ are you wanting to do this? If it is just to save money, then Stopping and Starting an instance will give most of the benefit. The extra saving on the EBS volume is hardly worthwhile because EBS is 8c/GB/month while snapshots/AMIs are 5c/GB/month. So, it really isn't worth the extra effort. Please tell us about your motivation for wanting to do these activities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The money is one aspect, yes but through terminating the instances it should be saved. But another point is to safe the data to S3 buckets instead of trusting that they are secure on a ESB

Comment: It's hard to offer any advice unless you can tell us your goals. If your goal is backups to ensure no data loss, then why terminate instances? If your goal is to save money, then tell us more about your system's usage patterns (eg do you need them running at night)? Is your app written such that you can store your data in S3 rather than EBS? How are your EC2 instances being used? etc.

Comment: The goal was to create an approach in which you can easily setup and provision a "fresh" instance from scratch, with all your installation/modifications, if you need to. All the data that had to be persisted had to get covered by a proper backup/recovery approach. So at the end you are able to deploy your ec2-infrastructure in e.g. newer versions without a data loss. And by newer versions i dont mean updates...its all about different modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Terraform to automate my deployment of the EC2-Instance with my wanted Applications.This is specified in a Script that runs automatically after launch, which you can also deploy in Terraform. So Terraform deletes and starts my Instance and for backup and recovery I also use scripts and crontabs. So the recovery of my persistent data is also specified right in the script that also installs the applications on my EC2-Instance and uses S3 Buckets through the aws cli. And the backup has its own script which is pulled through the Script in Terraform which also sets the crontab for it. =)